# Execute function while script running

Tags: python, function, execute

Alright this is a simple question, because i don't really know what its called..

Say i have a loop in python

```
if pattern in buffer:
        while logme == "y":
            logging.basicConfig(filename='hook.log',level=logging.DEBUG)
            logging.debug("Pre-Encrypted: %s" % buffer)
            print "Pre-Encrypted: %s" % buffer
        else:
            print "Pre-Encrypted: %s" % buffer
```

How can i make it so when i press a keyboard key like P while the loop is running and have it execute a command like pausing the loop, exiting, or doing anything? Like not command line arguments but while the actual program is running..

Comment: I think you might need to use threading to keep your loop going while you get input in another thread, since both `input()` and `raw_input()` are blocking.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Getch](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/134892/)

See [Python read a single character from the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/python-read-a-single-character-from-the-user)

Or use [curses](http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [curses](http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html), which would be a bit complicated.

A quick hack around it would be to intercept SIGINT (Ctrl-C, `KeyboardInterrupt`) in Python.

```
def foo():
  try:
     long_running_process()
  catch KeyboardInterrupt:
     deal_with_interrupt()
```

In addition to violating expectations about Ctrl-C behavior, this also doesn't provide an obvious way to restart the thing.